# I have ruby installed greater than 2.3.0 but it says requires greater than 2.3.0 for i18n to be installed

Tags: ruby, chef, gem

I have ruby version 2.5.1p57 when ran ruby -v command.
While installing a cookbook which requires i18n, it throws error

```
 i18n requires Ruby version >= 2.3.0.
```

Though the ruby version is greater than 2.3.0.
Can you help me identifying what could be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. It is appreciated anyone has the answer.

```
[cchiang@pxe1 lab_systems]$ sudo gem install activerecord
ERROR:  Error installing activerecord:
        i18n requires Ruby version >= 2.3.0.
[cchiang@pxe1 lab_systems]$ ruby -v
ruby 2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091) [x86_64-linux]
[cchiang@pxe1 lab_systems]$
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1085102)